# Assistance with PHP Form Validation

Tags: php, regex, forms, validation, email

I've been working on a php page to send mail to an email address and have been trying to add validation. I have gone wrong somewhere but I'm not sure where? The code is supposed to start validating after the submit button is pressed. Its supposed to check whether a field is empty then validate against a set regex however i think ive made an error. If the form is successfully validated it gets sent to my email.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST{'submit'} )){

    $f_name=$_POST['first_name'];
    $l_name=$_POST['last_name'];
    $email=$_POST['email']; 
    $message=$_POST['message']; 

    $to = "email@somewhere.com";
    $subject = "A message has been sent from your site";
    $comment = "You have been emailed by: $email \n
                Message Contents: $message \n
                Message sent by $f_name $l_name \n
                Email to respond to: $email" ;

    if (empty($_POST["f_name"]))
        echo "Please enter your first name";
        }
    else{
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$f_name))
            {
        echo "Your first name does not appear to be valid";
            }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["l_name"]))
        echo "Please enter your last name";
        }
    else{
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$f_name))
            {
        echo "Your last name does not appear to be valid.";
            }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"]))
        echo "Please enter your email";
        }
    else{
        if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
            {
        echo "Your email does not appear to be valid.";
            }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["message"]))
        echo "Please enter a message";
        }

        else{
                    mail($to, $subject, $message);

                    /* Print a message for the user */
                    echo "<b>Your message has been sent successfully, details are as followed:</b><br />";
                    echo "<br /><b>First name: </b>".$f_name;
                    echo "<br /><b>Last name: </b>".$l_name;
                    echo "<br /><b>Email: </b>".$email;
                    echo "<br /><b>Comments: </b>".$message;
                    echo "<br /><br /><b>Thank you for your comment.</b>"; 
    }else{
    ?> 
    <form  action="contact_page.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
    First Name:<br> 
    <input name="first_name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Surname:<br>
    <input name="last_name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your email:<br> 
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your message:<br> 
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Send email" name="submit"/> 
    <input type="reset" value="Reset Form">
    </form> 
    <?php 




?>
```

Comment: "however i think ive made an error". Ok, what is it doing that makes you think this?

Comment: There are **a lot** of errors in your script. Check if `if-else` blocks.

Comment: Also this form needs to work against MySQL injection, as well as exit() after the echos, unless your intention is to display all errors at once.

Comment: When you click submit a PHP error message appears. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}.

Comment: See, that was my thought but i got a little confused, i was finding it difficult to check for blanks and validate. All comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't breaking out everywhere, I believe the problem lies with

```
if (empty($_POST["message"])){
    echo "Please enter a message";
    }else{
                mail($to, $subject, $message);

                /* Print a message for the user */
                echo "<b>Your message has been sent successfully, details are as followed:</b><br />";
                echo "<br /><b>First name: </b>".$f_name;
                echo "<br /><b>Last name: </b>".$l_name;
                echo "<br /><b>Email: </b>".$email;
                echo "<br /><b>Comments: </b>".$message;
                echo "<br /><br /><b>Thank you for your comment.</b>"; 
}
```

To start: follow your curly braces, I think you are off a few, but ultimately, the way you're validating make it so that everything can be blank except for the message. So your validator just checks for a message block and executes the email.

I would make it something somewhat easier on yourself.

```
<div id="message">
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['first_name']) || isset($_POST['last_name') || [ETC.]){
     echo("I'm sorry, but all fields must be filled in.");
}else{
     mail($to, $subject, $message);

     /* Print a message for the user */
     echo "<b>Your message has been sent successfully, details are as followed:</b><br />";
     echo "<br /><b>First name: </b>".$f_name;
     echo "<br /><b>Last name: </b>".$l_name;
     echo "<br /><b>Email: </b>".$email;
     echo "<br /><b>Comments: </b>".$message;
     echo "<br /><br /><b>Thank you for your comment.</b>";
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Apparently I'm also a slow typer.

Comment: I see, so would that just make it less bloated as using or allows you to check them without listing everything off?

Comment: just less bloated, the single if where you compare all fields makes it easier on reading. Two IF statements help the long run. You could even include some CSS to make the div green or red depending on if they passed your test.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `if(isset($_POST['action']))` rather than `if(isset($_POST{'submit'} ))`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
```

This input will create a POST field with name `action` and value `submit` when the form is submitted. You can use this to change program flow at a high level, but still need to check for the existence of other fields using the `isset()` function before using them.

Your script will currently issue a notice if `$_POST['action']` exists but `$_POST['first_name']` doesn't.

You also have a fair number of extra `}` throughout causing syntax errors. Reverse indentation makes it far harder to spot these errors.